# what is the usage(benefit) of setting auto_increment not from 1 in sql?

Tags: sql

one of my professor asked me about "what is the practical usage or benefit of assigning auto_increment start value from i.e 5000 in sql" he told me try to search you will find something interesting,but I tried a lot, I couldn't find technical answer. is there any technical deference or it is just an optional task.

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
    grp ENUM('fish','mammal','bird') NOT NULL,
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (grp,id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=500;
```

Comment: Been working around databases for over 10 years and have not once heard of any benefit from setting a higher start value. The idea of how it could somehow cause a benefit makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: I share Skyhawk opinion. It sounds more as result of some thinking made in lab, not something that came from real world usage...

Answer (score 1):

One possible use is when you create what SQL Server calls partitioned views:

```
create table ObjectsOfTypeA (
  id int identity(10000, 1) primary key,
  check (id between 10000 and 19999),
  somefield varchar(10) );

create table ObjectsOfTypeB (
  id int identity(20000, 1) primary key,
  check (id between 20000 and 29999),
  somefield varchar(10) );

create table ObjectsOfTypeC (
  id int identity(30000, 1) primary key,
  check (id between 30000 and 39999),
  somefield varchar(10) );

create view AllObjects as
select * from ObjectsOfTypeA
union all
select * from ObjectsOfTypeB
union all
select * from ObjectsOfTypeC;
```

It would IMO be better to not use auto-increment/identity columns for this, but if you do use them, you *really* don't want to have them start at 1, because it would then violate the check constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Auto increment some times uses in database replication in order to make articles consistent.